# Split Out Shortcode Bracket from JSON Array Bracket With Compatibility

Tags: php, regex

Generally, I have a hard time with regex patterns beyond basic matching. I have a simplistic shortcode parser similar to how Wordpress has so an example is:

```
~PLUGIN::name_of_plugin["param1"="value1","param2"="value2"]~
```

I have this splitting and working, I just use `explode()` on the `[` and trim the `]` to get the parameters portion. Now, I want to pass a nested array so I am trying to do a JSON object into those brackets instead, so the string to parse would look like this:

```
$str    =   '~PLUGIN::name_of_plugin[{
            "category":"whatever",
            "test":[{
                    "name":"Title Something",
                    "desc":"123123-A",
                    "result":"Confirmation",
                    "conforms":"true",
                    "mass_spec":"true"
                }]
        }]~';
```

After a series of different pattern attempts with varying degrees of success, this is what I came up with that I would consider *useable*:

```
preg_match('/^\~([a-z]+::)([a-z\_\-]+)([^\~]+)\~/i',$str,$match);
print_r($match);
```

It matches to this (I can trim key `3` for what I need):

```
Array
(
    [0] => ~PLUGIN::name_of_plugin[{
                "category":"whatever",
                "test":[{
                        "name":"Title Something",
                        "desc":"123123-A",
                        "result":"Confirmation",
                        "conforms":"true",
                        "mass_spec":"true"
                    }]
            }]~
    [1] => PLUGIN::
    [2] => name_of_plugin
    [3] => [{
                "category":"whatever",
                "test":[{
                    "name":"Title Something",
                    "desc":"123123-A",
                    "result":"Confirmation",
                    "conforms":"true",
                    "mass_spec":"true"
                }]
            }]
)
```

The problem there is, if the shortcode doesn't have parameters like:

```
$str    =   '~PLUGIN::name_test~';
```

It splits out to this (notice the `n` in key `3`):

```
Array
(
    [0] => ~PLUGIN::name_of_plugin~
    [1] => PLUGIN::
    [2] => name_of_plugi
    [3] => n
)
```

Is there some sort of forward-looking thing I should be doing that would make this split out to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ~PLUGIN::name_of_plugin~
    [1] => PLUGIN::
    [2] => name_of_plugin
)
```

but also will split the parameters block out when it exists? I am trying not to do some sort of hack where I `implode()` key `2` and `3` or something.

Comment: Your `[^\~]+` requires at least one character that is not `~`. If you change the `+` quantifier to `*` it would allow zero as well.

Comment: @bobblebubble Thanks, I will take a look at that! Like I say, I'm a bit of a tool with regards to patterning...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this works by just making the last group optional. I only added `?` before the last `~`.

Also, `~` and `_` are not a special characters, so no need to escape them.

I also added the anchor for end of line `$`. It's usually a good idea if you want to make sure it captures the whole string.

```
^~([a-z]+::)([a-z_\-]+)([^~]+)?~$
```

See it work: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/giOhGT/3)

Comment: Yeah, I never know what is and not a reserved regex character so I always escape it if it *looks* like it could be.. This is does work, I didn't know that's what the `?` did. This does work like I am looking for. I appreciate it!

Comment: If you check out the top lines in the following link, you can see the special characters listed. https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharacters.html

Comment: Yikes, that is the site I was using to try and figure out a better pattern, I never made it to that page I guess...thanks though, I learned something!

Comment: That site has everything you need to know, but I realise it may be hard to navigate. Keep it up, you made a better effort than most people asking regex questions.